# SQL Server : WHERE Clause on a selected variable of a column

Tags: sql-server

I have table of 10k records, and would like to filter the data on a criteria.

Basically the criteria is on two columns one with int and other with text.

Sample Data :

```
Label   Value
A   24
A   18
A   15
A   35
A   27
A   37
B   18
B   29       
B   18
B   16
B   16
```

I wanted to filter and display the data excluding the `Value` < 20 and `Label` = A.

Please do help me out in getting an answer for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to exclude any values with value < 20 with a label = A or do you want to exclude any values < 20 (regardless of label value) and any rows with label = 'A' (regardless of value value)?

Comment: @SteveFord - Sorry for the late reply. I wanted to get all the values `WHERE [Label] = 'B' AND ([Label] = 'A' AND VALUE > 20)`. I only wanted to exclude data where the `([Label] = 'A' AND VALUE < 20)`

Answer (score 3):

How about this simple query?

```
Select * From MyTable Where Value >= 20 And Label <> 'A'
```

Comment: It's giving me values greater than 20 only for 'B'. But what I'm supposed to get is. I should get all the values from 'B' and wanted to exclude the values for only 'A' where the value of 'A' < 20.

Comment: I found a solution by wrting two queries for each condition and using union all to combine the result. But I wanted to do that in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were nearly there. try this:

```
Select * From MyTable 
Where [Label] = 'B' OR ([Label] = 'A' AND [Value] > 20)
```